# How Do I separate String from Integer and Save it

Tags: java, string, split, integer

I wanted to know how can I separate a string into two parts and save it in two different variables.

I have:

```
String str = "3-abc";
```

And want to save it in two Strings:

```
String part1 = "3";
String part2 = "abc";
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Use [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] strArray = str.split("-");
String part1=strArray[0]; 
String part2=strArray[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use split function

```
String[] temp;
String delimiter = "-";
temp = str.split(delimter);
for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
   System.out.println(temp[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method of `String` class. So

```
String[] parts = str.split("-");

String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
```

From [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

```
Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression. 


Returns:
    the array of strings computed by splitting this string around 
    matches of the given regular expression
```

Answer (score 0):

If strings are all in one format you can use `String[] splittedStrings = str.split("-");` After that try to convert your string to integer with `Integer.parseInt(splittedStrings[0]);`